# Get route parameters in component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router

I am working on the Angular-6 project. I have many child routes for my application. One of them is as follow:

```
  const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'innovation-track/:innovation-track-id', component: InnovationTrackComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'sprint', component: ScrumBoardComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I want to get **innovation-track-id** value from URL in my **ScrumBoardComponent**.

I know I can get this by doing following:

```
 constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) { }

 //somewhere in method     
   this._route.snapshot.parent.paramMap
```

But, I want to fetch **innovation-track-id** value in any component, doesn't matter if it is child or parent. What I mean is I don't want to do the following:

```
this._route.snapshot.parent.paramMap
```

Instead, I want to do something as following:

```
 this._route.params.<any parameter name>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a service (let's call it `RouteParamsService`) :

```
export class RouteParamsService {
  innovationTrackId = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);
}
```

In your parent component, subscribe to params :

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private service: RouteParamsService) {
  route.params
    .subscribe(params => service.innovationTrackId
      .next(params && params['innovation-track-id'] || undefined))
}
```

Now you can subscribe to your service in any component, and you will get the value of your param. The parent component will handle any value change, and the service will propagate the change to any component that subscribed to it.

Comment: That's what something I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Activated Route`. As index of the `params` array you can use any parameter name.

```
constructor(private itunes:SearchService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) {

    this.route.params.subscribe( params => params[<any parameter name>]); 
}
```

Comment: @trichetriche No, he especially asked for a generic way to query for parameters with their name. And my solution does that. Your solution just query for `innovation-track-id`.

Comment: `I want to fetch innovation-track-id value in any component, doesn't matter if it is child or parent`. And your solution isn't answering that, and it's not even the shortest way to do it.